# Laravel custom websocket handler not working

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

**web.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;
use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Server\Logger\WebsocketsLogger;

app()->singleton(WebsocketsLogger::class, function () {
    return (new WebsocketsLogger(new NullOutput()))->enable(false);
});

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Facades\WebSocketsRouter;

WebSocketsRouter::webSocket('/my-websocket', \App\MyCustomWebSocketHandler::class);
```

**MyCustomWebSocketHandler**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\RFC6455\Messaging\MessageInterface;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\MessageComponentInterface;
use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\WebSocketHandler;

class MyCustomWebSocketHandler extends WebSocketHandler
{

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $connection, MessageInterface $msg)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onMessage() method.
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:6001/app/websocketkey/my-websocket?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false");
```

When trying to run the client connection, it's not getting connected to the custom handler. The default handler is working fine.

*The `Websocket:serve` and `artisan:serve` are running*

referred articles [1](https://freek.dev/1228-introducing-laravel-websockets-an-easy-to-use-websocket-server-implemented-in-php) , [2](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/advanced-usage/custom-websocket-handlers.html)

Any thoughts on this.? [Tried with the demo here](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets-demo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the websocket route as below resolved the issue.

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;
use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Server\Logger\WebsocketsLogger;

app()->singleton(WebsocketsLogger::class, function () {
    return (new WebsocketsLogger(new NullOutput()))->enable(false);
});

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Facades\WebSocketsRouter;

WebSocketsRouter::webSocket('/app/{appkey}/my-websocket', \App\MyCustomWebSocketHandler::class);
```